# how to give limit in mongoexport in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to take backup of only 100 records from a collection how can i give limit in query -q.

here what i tried giving limit but after giving limit in -q it is not inserting any record.

```
mongoexport --host localhost --db test --collection foo  -q "{"limit":"1"}" > a.json
```

Please suggest how can i give limit number of record in mongoexport

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/mongoexport

Comment: feature is not available

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using a *nix (or cygwin), you could use head -100

```
mongoexport --host localhost --db test --collection foo  | head -100 > a.json
```

EDIT : as found on the mongodb mailing list, there is a feature request for this : https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2033

EDIT: this answer is more than 4y old. Mongodb has implemented a built-in feature, see other answers below.

Comment: we are using ubuntu ? how to do in ubutnu?

Comment: just open a terminal and copy-paste the provided line

Comment: tried not working  i  have 3 record in a collection and i don head -1 and it insert all the 3 record . check this link https://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/a9d3853ab1802173?hl=en&pli=1

Comment: What do you mean by "insert" ? It should write   all the lines output by mongoexport (except the line 'connecting to 127.0.0.1') in  the file a.json.

Comment: Does this stop the export from continuing, or will it still continue and page-in the entire collection, and just superficially write the first 100 rows?  ie could I run this on a large production collection without issue?

Comment: @ScottStafford it will stop the query from displaying more results. As queries return cursors (i.e not directly results but some of them+ link to next) your query will only load all results. However the cursor for the query needs to be created (without taking advantage of a "limit" operator whihc may lead to long queries)

Comment: also note that the ticket SERVER-2033 has been fixed and will be available in 2.6

Comment: This has now been implemented via the --limit parameter in mongoexport, i.e. "--limit 100" to take the top 100.  I found this page while looking, thought adding the argument here would be helpful for others.

Answer (score 41):

mongoexport supports limit, so simply:

```
mongoexport --host localhost --db test --collection foo  --limit 1 --out a.json
```

Comment: This should be the correct/accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

For those stuck on an older version of mongo that doesn't have the limit functionality, an alternative could be to run a query with limit that creates a new collection and export from this.

```
db.createCollection("limitedResults")
db.limitedResults.insert( (db.foo.find().limit(1)).toArray() )
```

then

```
mongoexport --host localhost --db test --collection limitedResults --out a.json
```